# identify who is logged in linux through authorized_keys file

Tags: linux, authentication, unix, authorized-keys

We have an environment where multiple users access the same server using the same functional account. This is by design and works well for our needs.

The authentication is done through the keys stored in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.
My problem happens when I logon to the server and I notice someone is doing some action but I don't know who it is.

My question is: Is it possible to intersept when someone logs in to the server and write into a logfile something like this:

```
<timestamp> <fingerprint from authorized_keys file> <functional account name>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the currently used ssh key from within the current ssh session, then it seems there’s a better way since [OpenSSH 7.6](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6):

Set `ExposeAuthInfo yes` in your server’s sshd_config. You should be able to limit this configuration to a specific user via `Match User geoaxis`.

Then, after restarting `sshd` and re-login, there should be an environment variable `SSH_USER_AUTH` that contains the path to a file with authentication information. In case of public key authentication this file contains the full public key prefixed with the string `publickey` .

This way you don’t need to manually add environment variables to your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.